# Is there any strategy to partition the responsibilities to apply SRP?

Tags: class, oop, design-patterns, single-responsibility-principle

**Is there any strategy to partition the classes to apply Single Responsibility Principle?**

In a medium size team, we are developing a wearable manager app which can connect with different types of wearables, let’s say, `Wearable1` and `Wearable2` (single connection at a time). Each wearable device has different types of capabilities to exchange data. So I decided to partition the responsibility based on wearable types. i.e.

```
interface Manager {
    // common functionalities
}

class Wearable1manager implements Manager {
    // Manages wearable1 specific functionalities
    // as well as wearable1 related capabilities
}

class Wearable2manager implements Manager {
    // Manages wearable2 specific functionalities
    // as well as wearable2 related capabilities
}
```

One of my colleagues is denying my design saying it is violating the `Single Responsibility Principle` (SRP) because Capability related functionalities should be handled by Single capability manager. His proposal is like,

```
interface Manager {
    // common functionalities
}

class WearableManager implements Manager {
    // Manages wearable1 specific functionalities
    // as well as wearable2 specific functionalities
}

class CapabilityManager implements Manager {
    // Manages wearable1 related capabilities
    // as well as wearable2 related capabilities
}
```

Basically, I found that we both are emphasising to apply Single Responsibility Principle but our thought of dividing responsibilities are based on different aspects. I often find me in such critical situation when I need to decide based on which responsibility I should partition the classes. So my question is,

Is there any specific guideline for OOP design which helps to take decision to partition the classes to apply SRP? Or is this dependent purely to experience? I hope there should be specific sets of steps to analyse and resolve this confusion. Suggestions from experienced are appreciated.

Comment: Both of these designs look wrong.  What are these "manager" classes *for*?

Comment: @Matt managers are for handling functionalities. Although it is supposed to contain wearable instances and other stuffs. I just shown the MWE to confront the actual problem of decision dilemma.

Comment: That's pretty vague.  A "Manager" class usually manages a collection of things or events, aggregates status, tracks additions and removals, etc. -- the same kind of stuff that a human "manager" does.  SRP means that each component does one job for one boss.  I don't see any job that needs doing or any boss that needs it done.  Without that, you're just partitioning code into multiple files, not designing software.  From the purpose of your app, it seems likely that you would need *one* WearableManager class + interface that manages the collection of wearables that the user owns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definition of Single Responsibility Principle:

> The single responsibility principle is a computer programming
>   principle that states that every module, class, or function[1] should
>   have responsibility over a single part of the functionality provided
>   by the software, and that responsibility should be entirely
>   encapsulated by the class, module or function. All its services should
>   be narrowly aligned with that responsibility. Robert C. Martin
>   expresses the principle as, "A class should have only one reason to
>   change,"[1] although, because of confusion around the word "reason" he
>   more recently stated "This principle is about people.(Actor)"[2]

As we can see we have the definition of **responsibility** in the definition above, let's formulate it into words:

> Responsibility equates to a logically bound part of the function
>   provided by the software.

So, if you have capabilities-related functionalities, you should have these implemented inside a single class/module, hence your colleague is right, your initial code divides the implementation of capabilities into two different Wearable Manager classes, which violates the principle, because capabilities-related functionality is a responsibility.

However, you also have a point in stating that different wearable managers have different capabilities. To cope with this, you will need an attribute for wearable manager instances which would identify what capabilities it has. This could be an array, a String or even an instance of a third manager, dealing with capabilities of wearables, as you can define the relation between capabilities and wearables as a separate responsibility.

SRP depends on your responsibilities. You need to define what the responsibilities are in your case. To do so, you need to partitionate your functionalities into logically bound partitions (the responsibilities) and from there on everything will fit into place. However, if you and your colleague have done different partitioning, then the two of you have different responsibility entities in your mind and it would be a wise idea to discuss this.

Responsibility as a concept is evidently definable, however, defining what your responsibilities are is your and your colleagues' job. The more experience and understanding of the problem, the better the partitions will be.

Answer (score 0):

There is no definition of "responsibility". As a consequece, there is no such strategy. However, there are: 1) barely definalbe common sense, 2) sense of a context you're woring in.

According to my personal experience, the right question to ask is "why would I ever need to change this code?". If there are more then one (business?) reason, it's a trigger to think more.

Comment: If there is no definition of `responsibility`, how on earth the SRP principle works?

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan, there is no definition of "love", nor "kindness", though both work well.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan, yeah, as long as you're doing sience, there must be. But "single responsibility" isn't a science. It's a hitrorically proven principle. Like democracy. It isn't measurable (equally, one can come up with hundreds of metrics that work in some precise sense, but don't scale well). OOP isn't a science, don't fool yourself.

Comment: Responsibility in terms of SRP can be defined as a partition of the functionalities, a logically bound part of the abilities of the software. As such, in abstract terms you can define the concept, but when you have to apply this principle on a given software, the concrete responsibilities need to be defined by you.

Comment: `SRP` is a `principle` and all `principles` are derived from scientific analysis (a part of science). However, there are debates on even science and philosophy as well. Don't misunderstand and fool me. @SerejaBogolubov

Comment: @LajosArpad, sure, as long as you're able to define what is functionality.

Comment: Sereja you have fallen into the Nirvana fallacy (which consists of avoiding doing something if you cannot do it perfectly). That's a logical fallacy. Of course we can define what functionality is. A simple search on the internet will yield you dozens of definitions. But if I would paste them here, you will notice that they are defined based on another concept and will refer to its definition. I, on my turn would be giving you that definition and the process will be repeated.

Comment: We are dealing with complex concepts and it's not in the scope of our discussion to start defining what functionality is or the concepts we use to define it. We could play that forever, but I do not have time for that. Professors in highschools or college/university have the job of defining and explaining such concepts. We, professional programmers have to concentrate on other things and teaching such simple concepts is not our best forte.